# Averageifs multiple column and rows for a table

Tags: excel

I am looking to do create a dynamic Averageifs with a table. Here is the sample data:

Sample Table:

[image: Sample Table]

Can anyone help me out on how to make the "A" and "B" dynamic? When I insert the cell number (D7,D8) it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out? I would really be thankful for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works if the range is contiguous.

```
=AVERAGE(IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH(D7:D10,D7:D8,0)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E6:H6,{"X","Y","Z"},0)))*(E7:H10<>0),E7:H10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So how would I be able to take out the average of a table using dynamic columns and rows. So for example in the sample above, how can I take out the average of "A" and "B" and "Z" and "L", such that I can change A to B and the answer changes.

Comment: The best is to create two lists in different cells so say column A for the values in D and Column B for the values in row 6 then: `=AVERAGE(IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH(D7:D10,A:A,0)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E6:H6,B:B,0)))*(E7:H10<>0),E7:H10))`

Comment: Wow. Wonderful. That will really help! Thank you sir. And I thought magic does not exist ;)

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer